# Node JS - get FQDN

Tags: node.js

How can I get the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) of the machine on which node is running?

`os.gethostname()` is not sufficient, since it usually returns the unqualified DN, only. Same thing for `dns.reverse(ip, callback)` - assuming the ip is the one associated with the hostname, e.g. obtained using `dns.lookup(os.gethostname()[, options], callback)`.

Also doing a `shell.exec("hostname -f", { silent: true }, cb)` is not an option, since it is **not POSIX compliant** and thus will fail e.g. on Solaris et. al., and it is a really bad hack, since exec() is a very, very **expensive** call wrt. resources like RAM and CPU (causes context switching).

Comment: `$(hostname).$(domainname)` will work on both Solaris and Linux. But, not only is Solaris POSIX, it's POSIX-certified! It's more POSIX than Linux is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should have been moved to SO

Answer (score 10):

The trick is to utilize the `getnameinfo(...)` function provided by the OS usually via libc.so or libsocket.so, since it does a FQDN lookup by default! Because `dns.lookupService(address, port, callback)` seems to be the only documented nodeJS core function, which "wraps" it, we need to use this one. E.g.:

```
var os = require('os');
var dns = require('dns');

var h = os.hostname();
console.log('UQDN: ' + h);

dns.lookup(h, { hints: dns.ADDRCONFIG }, function(err, ip) {
    console.log('IP: ' + ip);
    dns.lookupService(ip, 0, function (err, hostname, service) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('FQDN: ' + hostname);
        console.log('Service: ' + service);
    });
});
```

Port 0 is used in the example to show that this has no influence on the result (by default there is no service defined for this port).